# Xcode Project can not find .framework classes to import

Tags: swift, objective-c, frameworks, objective-c-literals, mobiledevice.framework

I am working on a project, that reads the bank cards. The card reader company provided a `.framework` SDK but does not provide any technical support.

I search on Google and find out how to add `.framework` into the project. I followed the following steps.

1. Drag and drop the framework file into the project folder.
2. Adding the framework into Build Setting -> Link Binary With Liberaries.
3. Adding the Framework Search Path into Build Settings.

After cleaning the project and rebuild still the framework classes are unknown to my project.

Do I miss something? or I am going on the wrong way.

My project is on Swift and the framework is on Objective-C.

Comment: Almost downvoted, but maybe there's a better way to help. (You really haven't given enough details, including something I could reproduce nor the framework details.) It's obvious that the framework, which I see doesn't provide any real support, isn't integrating with your project. And yes, no code nor details. So let's start with how you've tagged this - it's an ObjC framework? Have you tried to create one and incorporate it into your Swift app? That *might* point you in a direction to solve an issue you really haven't given enough detail about to duplicate.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I know your concern. The main issue is the documentation of this framework. It is not clear. The framework company told us that they do not have an iOS developer right now, they will hire soon.
I read a lot about how to import a framework inside a project. They helped me, but IDK why the framework is not recognizable for my project?
do you mean by "Have you tried to create one and incorporate it into your Swift app?”, I should create one framework and check it inside my project?
I don’t know, that what kind of information I should provide. Please help me :)

Comment: Thanks for the details. The only thing I hoped my suggestion would help with is to see if you are doing something wrong in incorporating the *real* framework into your project. If you can create a "dummy" framework that does nothing into your project, then the issue would be with the framework - but if you cannot even get Xcode to see your dummy framework the issue may be in how you are setting up your project.

Answer (score 0):

You need use bridge header and there you need to import your Objective C framework.

Comment: I created a Bridge Header for it, but the XCode does not recognize the framework to import. Also, this framework does not have main .h file. It has a lot of .h files. So, should I import all of them?

Comment: @AliQaderi more information would be required.